# CSS Limit HTML Width to Screen Width

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble limiting the  to the screen width on some browsers on my website.

The website in question is: https://teamcob4lt.eu

I'm using a 1920x1080px screen. On FireFox I can't scroll to the right, which is good. However on Chrome and some mobile browsers I can scroll quite a lot to the right using middle mouse button leaving a big gap in the page. There is no horizontal scroll bar though. This is happening to other people using Chrome whom I've asked to test the site as well. I don't want to people able to scroll on the x-axis at all meaning the "Base Layers" should fill the width of the screen all of the time.

Is it related to the fact that some elements are transformed backwards 300px? I can't seem to fix the issue using `overflow-x: hidden` either. Chrome is also leaving a large white gap at the bottom of the page 100% of the time. Is this related?

Is there anyway to fix this so that I am not able to scroll to the right on the page at all on any browser?

Here is the code which is causing the issue:

```css
/* Styles
--------------------------------------------- */

html {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.info {
  font-size: 2vw;
}


/* Parallax Base Styles
--------------------------------------------- */

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parallax__layer {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Style the Groups
--------------------------------------------- */

#groupH {
  z-index: 4;
}
#groupH .parallax__layer--base {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 50%;
}
#groupH .parallax__layer--back {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100);
}
#group1 {
  z-index: 4;
}
#group1 .parallax__layer--base {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 50%;
}
#group2 {
  z-index: 3;
}
#group2 .parallax__layer--base {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 50%;
}
#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 200);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/parallax.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="groupH" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="header" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base info">
        <div class="title">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="info1" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base info">
        <div class="title">Base Layer 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div id="info2" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base info">
        <div class="title">Base Layer 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't have anything overflowing X-wise on Safari or Chrome desktop on my Mac.

Comment: Try to add `initial-scale=1` to the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @j08691, I've added the code.

Comment: @alirezasafian I had that before, I can't remember why I removed it but it's still not working now...

Comment: @www139 Really? Myself and my friends are consistently getting the issue, but we've only tested properly in Chrome

Comment: The problem is `perspective: 300px;`.

Comment: @alirezasafian I have set `perspective: 0px` which obviously stops the parallax effect and it removes the white bars on the edges of the screen. However, instead it fills the space that would be white with the colour of the `parallax__layer--back` layer, meaning I can scroll just as far right as before.

Comment: Also, remove `transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);` from `.parallax__layer--back`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95804/discussion-between-apples292-and-alireza-safian).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue on my computer, neither in the snippet nor on the linked page. None of the browsers will scroll horizontally.

Comment: @MrLister Really?? Weird... I can't account for that